# httpUrlConnection post takes too long

Tags: android, post, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to post a multipart/form-data from an android device to a php server.

But when i post the data (a form and 2 PDFs files and a jpg picture max size 2mb each) i takes about 4 or 5 mins to get 200 response.

I did the debugging and it stops here:

```
  // checks server's status code 
    int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
```

Please help.

Comment: Why do you think we can help?

Comment: I'm new here have i done something wrong

Comment: Yes. You are not giving us the possibility to help you.